# Mr. Cool 24k mini split. Electrical install

Tags: electrical, heating, cooling

I'm getting ready to install a mr. Cool 24k mini split. The Electrical in the instructions is pretty vague. Just want to double-check that I'm correct on how I'm going to install it.

Inside my main breaker box gets a double pole 30 amp breaker. Then I run 10-3 to and outdoor a/c fuse box with two 25amp fuses in it. Then I run a whip cable into outdoor unit. Does that sound right? Thanks

Comment: Can you post a make/model number, a link to the specifications for your unit, or a photo of the outdoor unit's nameplate for that matter, please? Also, what make/model is your breaker box? (The fuses may not be needed/called for here, that' why I'm asking)

Comment: Unless they have changed something recently then that is right.

Comment: A **disconnect in sight of the outdoor unit** is required. That can be fused, or not fused, if the breaker provides the overcurrent protection needed.

Comment: DIY-24-HP-WMAH-230B

Comment: Inside breaker box is a GE 200amp

Comment: Or I should use 10-2 because there's no neutral on the outdoor unit?

Comment: You will also need a 120v receptacle in the area , what size unit are you installing? , just FYI make sure to use some blue nylog on the disconnects and check them after connecting with a bubble leak check solution. Leaking units were the major reason for failure of these units from a training class I had a while back.

Answer (score 2):

### Air conditioners don't quite follow the same rules as everything else out there

Due to the fact that hermetic air conditioning compressors invariably have overload protection built-in, the circuit breaker on an air conditioner circuit doesn't need to protect against a motor overload condition, just a short circuit.  Hence, the NEC lets you size wiring and protection for an air conditioner based on the Minimum Circuit Ampacity and Maximum Overcurrent Protection Device figures quoted by the manufacturer and listed on the nameplate, instead of using the general branch-circuit wire sizing rules.  (These figures obey rules found in NEC Article 440.)

In particular, according to [the brochure's specifications for your unit](https://mrcool.com/wp-content/dox_repo/mc-diy-3-b-br-en-01.pdf), it has a Minimum Circuit Ampacity of 18A and a Maximum Overcurrent Protection Device of 30A.  So, you could run 10/2 or 12/2 NM to the disconnect, since the unit has no use for a neutral wire, then run a prefab 1/2" flex whip kit (1/2" LFNC with 3x 12AWG) from a *non-fusible* pullout disconnect down to the outdoor unit. (The signal cable on these units is an integral part of the lineset, so it is routed with that instead of traveling up the flex whip.)

If you need a service receptacle at the unit, 12/4, 12/2/2, or 10/4 NM can be used instead, with the black and white wires used for the service receptacle and the red and blue (or white/red taped black, red, or blue) wires used for the 240V circuit to the air conditioner.  In all of these cases, you'll be using a THQL2130 or THQP230 (30A, 2 pole) breaker for the air conditioner circuit; while one could use a 25A breaker instead, that may lead to difficulty down the road (namely, false trips due to a hard starting compressor).  The service receptacle circuit, if present, is then connected to a general lighting circuit in the panel using wirenuts and 12AWG THHN pigtails to avoid a double tap on the breaker, by the way.